# Best way to learn the development of windows azure application & WCF services

Tags: wcf, azure

I am planning to learn the development of windows azure application & WCF services. 
Is there any learning structure (description of subject content) to follow/refer so that we can learn the subject efficiently

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the official [Windows Azure training kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8396) (filled with step-by-step guides, presentations, sample code, ...). Besides that you can also learn a lot from sites like [Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Tags/azure?sort=viewed), [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/), ... or by looking at sample projects on [CodePlex](http://mdtcustomizations.codeplex.com/site/search?tagName=,Azure,) or [GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=Azure%20WCF&type=Everything&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1).

Comment: +1 The Windows Azure Training Kit covers not only the basics, but I have found many scenarios in real world apps that can adapt solutions in the training kit.